# Compound conditions in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, syntax, generator, list-comprehension

Python allows an "`if`" condition in list comprehensions, e.g.:

```
[l for l in lines if l.startswith('example')]
```

This feature is missing in regular "`for`" loop, so in absence of:

```
for line in lines if line.startswith('example'):
    statements
```

one needs to assess the condition in the loop:

```
for line in lines:
    if line.startswith('example'):
        statements
```

or to embed the generator expression, like:

```
for line in [l for l in lines if l.startswith('example')]:
    statements
```

Is my understanding correct? Is there a better or more pythonic way than ones I listed above to achieve the same result of adding a condition in the for loop?

Please notice "lines" was chosen just as an example, any collection or generator could be there.

Comment: Are you asking how to get compound conditions in a for loop?

Comment: But these are exactly the same. You read the list comprehension from left to right, and it contains the exact same functionality as the full for loop.

Comment: Could you please say what exactly your question is?

Comment: @leaf: I expanded a little the question to make it more clear, pls let me know if you need more details.

Comment: @DanielRoseman not sure I understand your comment. All examples above are supposed to be isofunctional. The question is: why second syntax is not available in Python "for" loop, while it is there for list comprehensions? I guess it is due to the fact that the same goal is achievable with a different, more pythonic syntax, but I am not sure which one.

Comment: The functionality is already available through an `if` statement. There is no reason to shove more crud onto the `for` line. The `for` statement is not intended to replace or subsume the functionality of the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several nice ideas came from other answers and comments, but I think [this recent discussion on Python-ideas](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2016-September/042270.html) and [its continuation](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2016-October/042627.html) are the best answer to this question.

To summarize: the idea was already discussed in the past, and the benefits did not seem enough to motivate the syntax change, considering:

- increased language complexity and impact on learning curve
- technical changes in all implementations: CPython, Jython, Pypy..
- possible weird situations that extreme use of the synthax could lead

One point that people seem to highly consider is to avoid bringing Perl-alike complexity that compromise maintainability.

[This message](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2016-September/042273.html) and [this one](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2016-October/042651.html) nicely summarize possible alternatives (almost already appeared in this page as well) to a compound if-statement in for-loop:

```
# nested if
for l in lines:
    if l.startswith('example'):
        body

# continue, to put an accent on exceptional case
for l in lines:
    if not l.startswith('example'):
        continue
    body

# hacky way of generator expression
# (better than comprehension as does not store a list)
for l in (l for l in lines if l.startswith('example')):
    body()

# and its named version
def gen(lines):
    return (l for l in lines if l.startswith('example'))
for line in gen(lines):
    body

# functional style
for line in filter(lambda l: l.startswith('example'), lines):
    body()
```

Comment: `filter` should be the other way around: `filter(lambda l: l.startswith('example'), lines)`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not Pythonic, but you could `filter` the lines.

```
for line in filter(lambda l: l.startswith('example'), lines):
    print(line)
```

And you could define your own filter function, of course, if that lambda bothers you, or you want more complex filtering.

```
def my_filter(line):
    return line.startswith('example') or line.startswith('sample')

for line in filter(my_filter, lines):
    print(line)
```

I would say that having the condition within the loop is better because you aren't maintaining the "filtered" list in memory as you iterate over the lines.

So, that'd just be

```
for line in file:
    if not my_filter(line):
        continue
    # statements
```

Comment: Nice one, thanks. I tought about that but forgot to add it. Though, I still think it does not have the readability of just having a condition in the loop itself. I wonder if I am the first to feel the need of such syntax.

Comment: @Pintun FWIW, this was just discussed not too long ago on Python-ideas, where you can read the responses of some of the core CPython devs: [September 2016](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2016-September/042270.html), and continuing into [October 2016](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2016-October/042640.html). From what I gather, this idea has come up a few times before, as well. I strongly encourage you to read the whole thread.

Comment: @suspicousdog thanks, there I found everything I was looking for: a reference to a previous discussion, technical and aesthetical reasons in favour and against the change, great examples of alternatives. I found especially interesting [this](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2016-September/042273.html) message, that I will use as a guideline for a self-answer. I did not know [Python-ideas](https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/python-ideas), great link!

Answer (score 0):

Its not that the feature is missing, I can't think of any way it could be done except in some special cases. `(l for l in lines if l.startswith('example'))` is a generator object and the `l` variable is local to that object. The `for` only sees what was returned by the generator's `__next__` method.

The `for` is very different because the result of the generator needs to be bound to a variable in the caller's scope. You could have written

```
for line in (line for line in lines if l.startswith('example')):
    foo(line)
```

safely because those two `line`'s are in different scopes.

Further, the generator doesn't have to return just its local variable. It can evaluate any expression. How would you shortcut this?

```
for line in (foo(line)+'bar' for line in lines if line.startswith('example')):
    statements
```

Suppose you have a list of lists

```
for l in (l[:] for l in list_of_lists if l):
    l.append('modified')
```

That shouldn't append to the original lists.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better or more pythonic way than ones I listed above to achieve the same result of adding a condition in the for loop?

No, there is not, and there shouldn't be; *that was the rationale for why list comprehensions got here in the first place*. From the [corresponding PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/#id5):

> List comprehensions *provide a more concise way* to create lists in situations where `map()` and `filter()` and/or nested loops would currently be used.

List comprehensions constitute an alternative for nested `for`, `if`s;  why would you want an alternative to the alternative?

If you need to use an `if` with a `for`, you nest it inside it, if you don't want to do that, you use a list comprehension. *Flat is better than nested* **but** *readability counts*; allowing an `if` there would result in long ugly lines that are harder to visually parse.

Comment: "List comprehensions constitute an alternative for nested for, ifs; why would you want an alternative to the alternative?" They are not an alternative in this case: a comprehension list still need a for-loop to be iterated.